# Find last occurence of item in a list excluding the last element

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, this doesn't work when trying to find last occurrence excluding last element

`len(list) - 1 - list[::-1].index(1)`

```
list = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

It needs to find `index = 6`

Correct answer provided for a single list iteration.

Edited:

How to find the index of the last occurrence of number 1 in both lists with the same index?

```
list1 = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
list2 = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

The answer should be index = 4

Thank you

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: What does last element mean, last element in the entire list, or last occurrence of desired element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

**If you want to ignore last element**

```
lis = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]

print([i for i,v in enumerate(lis[:-1]) if v==1][-1])
# 6
```

**EDIT**

```
l1 = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
l2 = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]

ls1 = [i for i,v in enumerate(l1[:-1]) if v==1]
ls2 = [i for i,v in enumerate(l2[:-1]) if v==1]

val = None
# select the list with higer length here
for i in ls1[::-1]:
    if i in ls2:
        val = i
        break
print(val)
# 4
```

Comment: "If you want to ignore last element"
that works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: What about if there is a 2nd list

and i need to find the index where 1 occurs in the same index for both lists excluding the last element?

list1 =  [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
list2 = [3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]

Index should = 4

Comment: I need to find the last occurrence of both lists where the index is the same

Comment: It's really difficult to understand. Maybe you can ask new question or edit the same question with details.

Comment: Im getting an error with the above formula for a single list

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Genius. I see what's happening here. The initial iteration creates a list of occurrences and finds the last one excluding the last element. You then reverse iterate the 2 occurrences lists to find first occurrence in reverse. wd.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote it otherwise I would. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I have already upvoted the question. You need 15 or more reps to upvote. Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

The extra arguments to `index` might help you simplify the indexing:

```
len(lst) - 1 - lst[::-1].index(1, 1)
```

Since a list is reversible, you can avoid reallocations by using an iterator:

```
it = reversed(lst)
next(it) # discard last element
len(lst) - 2 - next(ind for ind, elem in it if elem == 1)
```